# positioning a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, tikz-trees

I have drawn a simple tree. But this code creates a left-aligned tree. How can I position the whole tree in the center?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\noautomath
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}    
\title{This is the title}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm}]
    \label{Figure1}
    \Tree 
    [.S 
      [.NP  [.PRP He ] ]
        [.VP
             [.VB ate ] 
              [.NP 
               [.DT some  ]                  
               [.NN pancakes ]                       
              ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    This is the content of this document.

    \end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a complete running code.

Comment: Use `\centering` inside a group or `the center` environment.

Comment: @CroCo, Sorry, I didn't know I should present the running code. I did so. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @HarishKumar, That absolutely worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\centering` or `\begin{center}...\end{center}` to center the tree:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\noautomath
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\title{This is the title}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    {\centering   %%<---- added
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm}]
    \label{Figure1}
    \Tree
    [.S
      [.NP  [.PRP He ] ]
        [.VP
             [.VB ate ]
              [.NP
               [.DT some  ]
               [.NN pancakes ]
              ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \par
    }
    This is the content of this document.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just added the image output.